# Differents in static methods and non static methods in classes without fields

Tags: c#, class, field, instance, instance-variables

Someone once wrote:

> The space required for an instance depends only on the fields.

> The methods require memory too but only one time per class. Like static fields. That memory is allocated when the class is loaded.

But what happens if a class with say like **5 methods** and **no fields** get multiple instances in fields of other classes(composition).
Do they require more memory? Or would it be the same as static methods?

I do ask this question also because maybe it even gets optimised when compiling?

Is there a differents to static class with static methods? Other than u need to create the class each time or pass it around?

Eg.:

```
class Test1
{
    public void DoThis()
    {
        ...
    }

    public void DoThat()
    {
        ...
    }
}

class Test2
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        ...
    }

    private Test1 sample = new Test1();

}

class Test3
{
    public void DoSomethingElse()
    {
        ...
    }

    private Test1 sample = new Test1();

}

And so on...
```

Comment: who is "someone" ?

Comment: It was a question on stackoverflow somewhere, but i cannot seem to find it anymore. It had like 5 upvotes or so so I assume it is or was somewhat true. But this has little to do with the question here.

Comment: Once again not the question but I am asking this mainly because in a larger scale than this it would have a impact IF there would be more memory consumption.

Comment: @It is not so simple. For the start you need to select a good text book and learn by heart hundreds pages about the memory management if you want to understand how it works.

Comment: @Serge So I assume u mean that there is no answer to this question that can be answered without reading hundred of pages? If so Thank you for your time. Also can u maybe recommend a good C# book what is fairly modern and or good? (In your opinion)

Comment: @MIkey I am sorry if your don' t understand what I mean, but my point is that you  should think and ask this kind of question after you create 10-20 applications. Trust me what are you asking for it is not the main problem to create a good application. There are alot much more important topics you should start from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Behind the scenes", a class method is just like a static method, with the class instance beeing passes by reference as the first parameter.

That is, unless you use [virtual methds](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/virtual-method-in-C-Sharp/), which "behind the scenes" are saved as instance members.

That is, because as long as you don't override a method, there is simply no reason to waste an instance's space.

Therefore, the size of both your class instances won't be affected by any non-virtual method you add to the class.

This concept can change between programming languages tho. For example, in `Java` and `Python` class methods are virtual by default.

Comment: well it's definitely not false. I can only assume that someone thought I wasn't beeing exact enough or something, or maybe didn't see what language you were asking about. But this is a general description of how class methods work in C#.

Comment: @aviad1 you should read the guide on how a question is useful and how an answer is useful. The question should be vote to closed, don't be answered to obtain points. This is not a game

Comment: Neither you should upvote it.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli I didn't upvote the question. And I don't collect points. I've only started answering questions on this site. I saw a genuine quesion about memory usage, and I tried to answer it in a brief, logical way, form my knowledge. I'm not some sort of point collector and I'm sorry if I did something wrong. But personally, I think that this is an OOP principle that is important to understand.